# How to open a file in vscode under wsl using the vscode:// url?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote

I would like to **open a file in vscode under WSL** (Windows Subsystem Linux) **using the `vscode://` url.**

You can do it with a normal file in the usual filesystem `vscode://file/c:/myProject/package.json`

 It is clearly explained in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_opening-vs-code-with-urls)

I would like to open **a file which is located in WSL**, so to have something like this
`vscode://file/home/user/myProject/package.json`

But It does not work !

It does not work to use the complete path in windows as it does not start the WSL vscode
`vscode://file/C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Packages\TheDebianProject.DebianGNULinux_76v4gqsdeaz4\LocalState\rootfs/home/user/myProject/package.json`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following scheme `vscode://file//wsl$/Ubuntu-18.04`
In your case it will be `vscode://file//wsl$/Ubuntu-18.04/home/user/myProject/package.json`
But unfortunately file is opened in a new window.
Please see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/99691

Comment: This will open the file in a new local window of  `vscode` but it will not open it in with `remote-wsl`. Unfortunately will be problematic for many users as `extensions` and `settings` very from local and remote connections.

Comment: As mentionned by hcoat, it is not opening vscode under WSL. So it is not solving my issue :(

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. I can configure react devtools to link to component source files in vscode wsl2 using `vscode://file//wsl$/YOUR_DISTRO_FOLDER{path}:{line}`. you can find the exact folder name for YOUR_DISTRO_FOLDER by pasting `\\wsl$` in the file explorer address bar and copying the folder name you find there.

Answer (score 1):

To open a remote window, don't use `file` but `vscode-remote`.

Please try `vscode://vscode-remote/wsl+distro+name/path/to/file`

Source: [Opening VS Code with URLs doesn't work with \wsl$ urls](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/99691)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer in another stackoverflow question

Source: [URL for opening vscode in file in WSL workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66582696/url-for-opening-vscode-in-file-in-wsl-workspace)

This answer is  based on the answer of equiman but you must indicate a line number for the file to open correctly.

```
vscode://vscode-remote/wsl+distroname/path/to/file:1
```

The 1 at the end indicates simply the first line of the file.