# URL for opening vscode in file in WSL workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to generate clickable links in the exception handler of my web application that open the corresponding source code in vscode.

Visual Studio Code provides the `vscode://file/` schema handler for this as [documented under command line docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_opening-vs-code-with-urls).

Unfortunately, this does not understand file links which are inside the Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Any idea how to generate links which open the `code` editor on a particular file (+ line)?

---

**Edit:** It seems it doesn't currently work and it did not make the backlog:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/111188

---

**Edit 2:**

- What works is using the command line/bash to open the file:

  `code -g -r /path/to/file`
- There is way to build links that opens a remote workspace or folder:

  `vscode://vscode-remote/wsl+${WSL_DISTRO_NAME}/path/to/dir`

---

**Edit 3:** Yeah! [As mentioned in Ryan's answer](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108257) there is now a way to open files by appending line numbers to the URL:

```
`vscode://vscode-remote/wsl+${WSL_DISTRO_NAME}/path/to/file.ext:1`
```

With this I can [finally click links in the Better Error Gem to open in VSCode](https://github.com/BetterErrors/better_errors/wiki/Link-to-your-editor#visual-studio-code).

Note: If the file does not exist then a new workspace is opened unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Just wanted to note that it should be a plus sign (`+`) and not a dash (`-`) in this segment of the url: `.../wsl+${WSL_DISTRO_NAME}/...`

Answer (score 2):

I found this thread to be the most helpful for finding accurate information:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108257

The OP was pretty much there, but I wanted to give a full rundown:

- It is not possible to `stat` a remote file path to determine if it's a directory or a file ([comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108257#issuecomment-707599904)).
- Therefore, all paths are considered a directory unless the path ends in `:linenumber[:column]` ([comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108257#issuecomment-824323473))
- You can simply append `:1` to the path to make sure it's treated as a file.

Here are some examples of urls which worked:

```
vscode://vscode-remote/wsl+Ubuntu-18.04/home/me/src/myexpressapp/app.js:1
vscode://vscode-remote/wsl+Ubuntu-18.04/home/me/src/myexpressapp/app.js:1:20
vscode://vscode-remote/wsl+Ubuntu-18.04/home/me/src/myexpressapp/app.js:20:1
vscode://vscode-remote/wsl+Ubuntu-18.04/home/me/src/myexpressapp/
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan! Did you find a way to make this usable though? When I click such a link it closes my current workspace and opens it for the given file.

Comment: Ah, okay, need to add `:1` to make sure it is treated as a file.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately opening a directory will close your current workspace - not sure there's any way around that. I only ever intend to link to files anyways, so it's no big deal for me.